# Can someone tell me what is the name of this controller?

Tags: ios, uitabcontroller

I'm looking and trying to find a doc about creating something like a tabbed view but on the top of the screen. I believe it's a plug'n play component, so, can someone tell me please the name of this component?

[image]

Comment: Please review the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/) document.

Comment: I can see it here
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/segmented-controls/ and here https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/navigation-bars/ and this link is broken to me 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol
I can't understand yet how to apply or use it

Comment: Every one of those links works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have circled there is a segmented control

Comment: So is the one with broken link https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: This link isn't broken?

Comment: Thanks man! With the name I found what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem.  Good luck